# c++ multiple interfaces to the same functionality template

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I have several methods that work over utf8 encoded strings that I usually keep in std::string.

In same cases though I just have const char* to the data, or the data is part of a bigger string I do not want to create a substring.

All the functionality boils down to one generic method say:

```
void foo(int a, int b, const char* beginStr, const char* endStr);
```

Now if I would like to avoid some ugliness I will create

```
void foo(int a, int b, const char* beginStr, const char* endStr);
void foo(int a, int b, const char* str);
void foo(int a, int b, const std::string% str);
```

and in some cases even:

```
void foo(int a, int b, const std::string::const_iterator& beginStr
                       const std::string::const_iterator& endStr);
```

This seems Ok, but as I mentioned I have several methods and it gets really annoying maintaining all these flavors.

What I am looking is some magic that could eliminate the need of multiplying every interface. Can some of the c++11 features help with solving this without performance impact - making it less chaty?

Comment: Why do some methods have two const char* and others one?

Comment: With two handles when you passing a range, with one is when you know only the beginning and it is zero terminated.

Comment: @Amit I will probably prefer to maintain them manually over macro, but now when you mentioned it, it does not seem so easy to do even with a macro.

Comment: Not in C++11, but http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view will be nice when rolled out. Or you can just use the experimental implementation.

Comment: A rule of thumb is that most things you do repetitively with small variations (function name for example), you should be able to do with a macro. But that's not to say everything can and should be done this way.

Comment: I suppose `void foo(int a, int b, const char* beginStr, const char* endStr);` is the function where you will put the entiere code, in the others you have to call it with the good parameters. You don't have the choice :)

Comment: @rici this is what I as thinking, some kind of a wrapper that could be constructed without performance penalty from all these flavors. The problem is the range cannot be implicitly handled this way. The string view concept seems great though.

Comment: @gsf: Why not? You can use `basic_string_view(&*beginStr, endStr - beginStr);`

Comment: @rici yes, but this is explicit. On the other side I might be asking for too much, because implicitly resolving this might create issues when multiple strings are in the interface.

Comment: @rici do you know for a open source public domain implementation of basic_string_view that I can start from?

Comment: @gsf: It doesn't need to be totally explicit. It's a bit annoying that you have two things instead of a single range, but you can define an implicit conversion from your own range object (containing two iterators) into a string_view. So you'd need to write foo(a, b, myrange(s.begin()+1, s.end())); but that's not awful.

Comment: @gsf: There are implementations in gcc (4.9 I think) and llvm's libc++; the latter is not exactly public domain but it's unrestricted afaik. You'd probably need to do a bit of work to disentangle the libc++ infrastructure. But if you're using a reasonably recent gcc or clang install, you should be able to just use it. It's standards track, so it should be safe. (I hope :-) )

Comment: @rici yeap, the clang I am using already has it so I will give it a try, thanks

Comment: Variadic templates combined with type traits should work. Look into template specialisation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment a wrapper as a `basic_string_view` may solve a part.
Variadic template may solve the other part (don't use *explicitly* `basic_string_view`):

```
void foo_impl(int a, int b, const basic_string_view& str); // the real implementation

template <typename ... Ts>
void foo(int a, int b, Ts&&... args) {
    foo_impl(a, b, basic_string_view{std::forward(args...)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Deleted my prior 2 answers, hopefully third time is the charm.)

This is just Jarod42's solution, but without the dependence on `basic_string_view`.

```
struct dispatcher {
  dispatcher(const char* begin, const char* end) : begin(begin), end(end) {}
  dispatcher(const char* str) : begin(str), end(str+strlen(str)) {}
  dispatcher(const std::string& str) : begin(&*(str.begin())), end(&*(str.end())) {}
  const char* begin;
  const char* end;
};

struct main_class {
  void foo(int a, int b, const char* begin, const char* end) {
    // implementation here
  }

  template<typename... Ts>
    void foo(int a, int b, Ts&&... args) {
      dispatcher d(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
      foo(a, b, d.begin, d.end);
    }
};
```